# Is it possible to add any error class in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to add any error class in erb file. I have 2 error classes defined in styles.css

app/assets/stylesheet/styles.css

```
label.validate {
  #styles
}

label.validate1 {
  #styles
}
```

My html.erb

```
 <div style="width:570px; border:none;" class="controls">
   Starting<%= text_field_tag :from_date, (Date.today), readonly: false %> 
   Ending <%= text_field_tag :to_date, (Date.today), readonly: false %>
 </div>
```

I would like to validate **Starting** field with **label.validate1** and **Ending** field with **label.validate** error classes. how should I add error classes in my erb?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to add a html class or for a proper way to check for errors and add the appropriate class as needed? Because adding a html class is as simple as appending `, class: 'validate'` to the `text_field_tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the classes you defined in css, can be applied on Labels, so you have to write labels for that, like this:

```
<div style="width:570px; border:none;" class="controls">
  <%= label_tag 'from_date', 'Starting', class: 'validate1' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :from_date, (Date.today), readonly: false %> 
  <%= label_tag 'to_date', 'Ending', class: 'validate' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :to_date, (Date.today), readonly: false %>
</div>
```

Hope it will work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add the class ONLY when there is an error with that attribute? If so, you can add class based on conditions

```
<div style="width:570px; border:none;" class="controls">
   <label class="<% (@form.errors[:from_date].present? ? 'validate1' : ''%>">
   Starting <%= text_field_tag :from_date, (Date.today), readonly: false %></label> 
</div>
```

Note: Replace `@form` with your actual instance variable name. You can follow same method for Ending one.